# Spring Annotation for factory-method

Tags: java, spring

I have following oracle connection pool factory defined. Question is do i have to inject entire factory instance to bean or some way i can inject `OracleConnectionPoolDataSource` into bean?

```
    <bean id="oraclePooledDataSourceFactory" class="oracle.ucp.jdbc.PoolDataSourceFactory" factory-method="getPoolDataSource">
    <!-- DataSource Class to be used -->
    <property name="connectionFactoryClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleConnectionPoolDataSource"/>
    <!-- Connection -->
    <property name="URL">
        <value>${jdbc.connection.url}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="user">
        <value>${jdbc.connection.username}</value>
    </property>
    <property name="password">
        <value>${jdbc.connection.password}</value>
    </property>
```

***Bean Annotation:??***

```
    @Autowired
@Required
@Qualifier("oraclePooledDataSource") <------ ????
public void setDatabaseSource(OracleConnectionPoolDataSource databaseSource) {
    this.databaseSource = databaseSource;
}
```

Comment: Refer 3.2.3.2.3. section: Instantiation using an instance factory method in following link
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/beans.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this works...
Remove the factory-method attribute from your `oraclePooledDataSourceFactory` definition and introduce another bean definition.

```
<bean id="oraclePooledDataSource" factory-bean="oraclePooledDataSourceFactory"
  factory-method="getPoolDataSource"/>
```

In your class autowire keep it like the way you mentioned. I am not sure if you need `@Required` attribute